# Google apps script error: The resource you requested could not be located

Tags: google-apps-script, google-calendar-api

Have a script that runs every five minutes, generally successfully.  Intermittently (1 to 4 times per day) it will throw an error.  There doesn't seem to be any rhyme or reason as to why it sometimes succeeds or fails.

The error is "The resource you requested could not be located. (line 48)"

```
44. var eventStart = event.getStartTime();
45. var eventRangeEndDate = eventStart;
46. var eventRangeStartDate = new Date(eventStart.getTime() - 600000); // removes 10 minutes
47. var calendar = CalendarApp.getDefaultCalendar();
48. var events = calendar.getEvents(eventRangeStartDate, eventRangeEndDate);
```

Nothing wonky in the execution transcript.  This error doesn't mean much to me and bizarre that it's inconsistent (usually the script works just fine).

Any thoughts?

Comment: please see the answer I posted on [this very similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863155/how-do-i-debug-intermittent-errors-with-calendarapp/13866077#13866077)

Comment: @Sergeinsas Thanks! I'll do that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I debug intermittent errors with CalendarApp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13863155/how-do-i-debug-intermittent-errors-with-calendarapp)